# Cancellation of multiple tasks in TPL based on return resutl

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task, cancellation-token

I have a scenario in which i have multiple functions to call in parallel and I am using TPL for that task. I have used

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<result>> dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<result>>();

var tasks = Task.Run(()=>
{
  new Task(()=> {dictionary.TryAdd("First", CallFirstFunction());});
  new Task(()=> {dictionary.TryAdd("Second", CallSecondFunction());});
  new Task(()=> {dictionary.TryAdd("Third", CallThirdFunction());});
  new Task(()=> {dictionary.TryAdd("Fourth", CallFourthFunction());});
});
```

Now, i need to wait till all the function are executed and return some result in concurrent dictionary so i can used it for further process, But i also want to cancel any task if some returned result is empty regardless of task order. If any function returns the empty result i need to cancel all remaining tasks at the same time. I have checked the "CancellationToken" class as well but i am confused to use this with in the tasks and how to share the function states with in the tasks.

Any help will be appreciated.
Best Regards

Comment: If you need the result, you have to wait for it. check `Task.WaitAny`

Comment: Why are you creating all those cold tasks? Instead of `new Task` just use `Task.Run` with a CancellationToken. Or use [Parallel.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783942(v=vs.110).aspx) if you don' mind blocking the main thread until they complete. `Parallel.Invoke` can also accept a cancellation token

Comment: @MikeDebela there is no need to block and wait, `await Task.WhenAll()` will await asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

To support cancellation you need to work with CancellationTokenSource. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674886.aspx

What you need to do is to pass the `CancellationTokenSource` to your methods so when the result is empty you can call `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()`

```
async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var ct = cts.Token;

    var tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        Task.Run(() => AddToDictionary("First", () => CallFirstFunction(), cts), ct),
        Task.Run(() => AddToDictionary("Second", () => CallSecondFunction(), cts), ct),
        Task.Run(() => AddToDictionary("Third", () => CallThirdFunction(), cts), ct),
        Task.Run(() => AddToDictionary("Fourth", () => CallFourthFunction(), cts), ct),
    };

    try
    {           
         await Task.WhenAll(tasks); 
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
    }
}

private void AddToDictionary(string key, Func<List<int>> method, CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    if(cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        return;

    var result = method.Invoke();
    if(!result.Any());
        cts.Cancel();

    if(!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        dictionary.TryAdd(key, result);
}
```

This example assumes that the operations you call (CallFirstFunction etc.) are not async (don't return a Task or Task). Otherwise you should pass the `CancellationToken` to them as well and check for cancellation using `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`

Cancelling a Task generates an OperationCanceledException you need to handle.

Of course, when any method is already completed before another one returns an empty result, those results will already be present in the dictionary. If you need other behaviour this example will give you some basic idea about how the `CancellationTokenSource` relates to Tasks and CancellationTokens